# Let $X$ be a closed proper subspace of $V$. Prove $\forall \alpha\in (0,1), \exists x\in V$ such that $\|x\|=1$ and $\inf_{y\in X}\|Tx-Ty\|\geq\alpha$

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Let $(V,||\cdot||)$ be a normed space and $X\subset V$ a closed, proper subspace. Let $T\in B(V)$ such that $(1-T)V\subset X$. Prove that, given $\alpha\in (0,1)$, there exists $x\in V$ with $\|x\|=1$ such that $\inf_{y\in X}\|Tx-Ty\|\geq \alpha$, where

$$B(V)=\{T:V\to V; T \text{ is bounded}\}$$

First thing that came to mind is Riesz's Lemma. Since $X$ is a closed proper subspace of $V$, then for $\alpha\in (0,1)$, there exists $x\in V$ such that $\|x\|=1$ and $\|x-y\|\geq \alpha$ for all $y\in Y$, so I only need to prove $\inf_{y\in X}\|Tx-Ty\|\geq \alpha$. How to use the fact that $T$ being a bounded operator implies $(1-T)V\subset X$?

Comment: What about $T=0$?

Comment: I would to apply Riesz in the image space of T or something, and then look for conditions in which this is true.

Comment: @copper.hat $T=0$ is not the case here, since then $(1-T)V\subset X$ means $V=X$, but $X$ is supposed to be proper

Comment: @R.W.Prado I thought the same thing at first, but apparently after noticing that $TX\subset X$, there's no need for that

Comment: @JustDroppedIn The question needs to be updated.

Comment: @copper.hat Despite the weird notation, is there a problem with the statement that I didn't catch? What I meant is that the other conditions immediately yield $T\ne 0$.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn I missed that, I thought the inclusion was part of the OP's commentary, not an assumption.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn I didn't know some statements were confusing. (English is not my main language). I just edited the question so is clearer now. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I will restate the question with the notation I'm going to use because the notation established in the original post confuses me.

> Question: Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a normed space and $Y\subset X$ a closed, proper subspace. Let $T\in B(X)$ be a bounded operator such that $(1-T)X\subset Y$. Show that, given $\alpha\in(0,1)$, there exists $x\in X$ with $\|x\|=1$ such that $\|Tx-Ty\|\ge\alpha$ for all $y\in Y$.

Proof: First, note that $(1-T)Y\subset (1-T)X\subset Y$, so $y-Ty\in Y$ for all $y\in Y$. Write $Ty=y-(y-Ty)\in Y$ to conclude that $T(Y)\subset Y$. Since $Y$ is closed and proper, we now apply [Riesz lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma) to obtain $x\in X$ with $\|x\|=1$ such that $\|x-y\|\ge\alpha$ for all $y\in Y$, so $\inf_{y\in Y}\|x-z\|\ge\alpha$.

Recall the quotient norm on $X/Y$: we have $\|x+Y\|=\inf_{y\in Y}\|x-y\|$. Now since $(1-T)X\subset Y$, we have that $x-Tx\in Y$, so $Tx+Y=x+Y$, so $\|Tx+Y\|_{X/Y}=\|x+Y\|_{X/Y}$, so $\inf_{y\in Y}\|Tx-y\|=\inf_{y\in Y}\|x-y\|\ge\alpha$. Therefore we have $\|Tx-y\|\ge\alpha$ for all $y\in Y$. Since $T(Y)\subset Y$ we conclude that $\|Tx-Ty\|\ge\alpha$ for all $y\in Y$, as we wanted.